# Changing Shaka player locale

Tags: shaka

The website I'm making has an option to switch display language between German and English. Shaka player seems to have support for localization switching, but I couldn't manage to display the player in anything other than English.
Tried using changeLocale on a new shaka.ui.Localization instance, but it doesn't appear to have an effect on the player.

Would appreciate any example of switching between locales.

Answer (score 1):

From the [GitHub repo's issues](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/3464),

`ui.getControls().getLocalization().changeLocale(['de'])` will switch to a German locale.